# Vue.js and Codenvy?

Tags: vue.js, npm, eclipse-che, codenvy

im trying to get a basic vue.js workspace up and running.
But it seems that anything i tried does not work.
Builting it up myself or use a git repo won't work at all.

Is it even possible get it work?

**Reproduction Steps:**

1. created blank workspace with debian, ubuntu or later i tried with the "node" preset
2. installed node.js
3. installed vue-cli
4. installed vue with webpack without anything special
5. installed dependencies
6. run the command or some variations of it

`cd vueapp01 && echo -e "\nWill start at ${server.3000}\n\nInstalling packeges..." && npm install && PORT=3000 npm run start`

**with the output:**

```
cd vueapp01 && echo -e "\nWill start at 
http://node21.codenvy.io:34463/\n\nInstalling packeges..." && npm install && 
PORT=3000 npm run starthttp://node21.codenvy.io:34463/

Will start at http://node21.codenvy.io:34463/

Installing packeges...
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is 
installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 
(node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

up to date in 6.051s

> vueapp01@1.0.0 start /projects/vueapp01
> npm run dev


> vueapp01@1.0.0 dev /projects/vueapp01
> webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js

DONE  Compiled successfully in 2712ms12:26:25

I  Your application is running here: http://localhost:3000
```

But the browser allways shows: Das System antwortete: (111) Connection refused

Also i tried to import a repo from git... i tried 4 or 5 ... nothing worked

**Codenvy version:**
5.22.1

Comment: When trying to replicate this (with CLI 3.0, though) I ran into an "Invalid Host header" message in the browser. Looks like you have to allow the webpack dev server to accept connections from hosts other than "localhost", check https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/1205 and try the `--host 0.0.0.0` way or the `disableHostCheck: true` one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For knowledge transfer:

Got it working with the hint that yuriy gave me.

"config/index.conf" changing `host:"localhost"` to `host:"0.0.0.0"`

In condenvy ist looks like:

```
module.exports = {
dev: {
// Paths
assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
assetsPublicPath: '/',
proxyTable: {},

// Various Dev Server settings
host: '0.0.0.0', // can be overwritten by process.env.HOST
port: 8080, // can be overwritten by process.env.PORT, if port is in use, a free one 
will be determined
autoOpenBrowser: false,
errorOverlay: true,
notifyOnErrors: true,
poll: false, // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver- 
watchoptions-
```